# Inverted Polygon in Flutter_Map

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

I have to use Flutter Map for my project and I'm using PolygonLayerOptions to draw a polygon, but how can I fill every place on my map except the interior of the polygon. Like the image below.
[image]

```
PolygonLayerOptions(
          polygons: [
            Polygon(
              points: [
                LatLng(-25.290800, -52.716573),
                LatLng(-25.065827, -47.402915),
                LatLng(-27.847390, -47.402915),
                LatLng(-27.792425, -52.654425),
                LatLng(-25.290800, -52.716573),
              ],
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),
              disableHolesBorder: true,
              isDotted: false,
              borderStrokeWidth: 5.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Hi there, you may want to try defining your polygon points as the four corners of the map, and then use the hole points list as the thing to leave unfilled. Happy to help you more on the Discord server!

Comment: anu update on this?!